# How can I read key input on windows in Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, input

I want to develop some utility on perl for autocompleting words.
Is there any effective way in Perl to hook the keyboard on win32 (thread hook/surelly not system hook  ) and catch an event when a key is clicked?

I want to intercept the keyboard before the message sent to the OS like setwindowshookex win32 api and to process the message (add the autocompletation functionality ) then continue currently i have app with richedit text when the user write on the app a word he wrote before (we saved on some place ) then the autocomplation done.

I know it can be done with the use of win32::api

If there a module on perl that do that for me it could be awesome ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a CPAN module for this: [Term::ReadKey](http://search.cpan.org/dist/TermReadKey/ReadKey.pm). You may also want to check out [perldoc -f getc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getc.html). There's nothing really in your question that's unique to Perl -- you just want to read characters from a buffer or stdin and process them individually.

Answer (score 0):

On Win32, if you want full control over the console, you can do so with the use of [Win32::Console](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::Console).